# less-like pager for (swi) prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, pager, prolog-toplevel, less-unix

The typical workflow in unix is to use a pipeline of filters ending up with a pager such as less. E.g. (omitting arguments)

```
grep | sed | awk | less
```

Now, one of the typical workflows in the swi-prolog's command line is asking it to give the set of solutions for a given conjunction like

```
foo(X),bar(X, Y),qux(buz, Y).
```

It readily gives me the set of soutions. Which can be much longer than the terminal window.  Or a single query

```
give_me_long_list(X).
```

can give a very long list again not fitting on the screen. So I constantly find myself in situations where I want to slap `|less` at the end of the line.

What I am looking for is a facility to open in a pager a set of solutions or just a single large term. Something similar to:

```
give_me_long_list(X), pager(X).
```

or

```
pager([X,Y], (foo(X),bar(X, Y),qux(buz, Y))).
```

Comment: What about adjusting the terminal to scroll? Usually hundreds if not thousands of lines can be in the scroll buffer.  Prolog could also be run in Emacs to provide unlimited scrolling. Use Emacs *shell* mode or some extension such a [ediprolog](http://www.logic.at/prolog/ediprolog/ediprolog.html).

Comment: use `portray_clause` and the terminal to scoll?

Comment: have already looked into library([solution_sequences](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)), specifically **reduced/3** ?

Comment: At least, SWI permits to enter SPACE to see the next answer. This was inspired by less/more/pg

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but wouldn't it be rather easy to write your own `pager` predicate? Steps:

1. [Create temp file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.34%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/files.html%27%29%29#tmp_file_stream/3)
2. dump `X` into temp file with the help of [these](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.22%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/strings.html%27%29%29) or [those](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.15%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) predicates

   (I haven't done any I/O with Prolog yet, but it doesn't seem too messy)
3. [make a system call to `less <tempfile>`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.33%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/system.html%27%29%29)